# How to create a relationship between to models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a small project management app for learning purposes using rails. I have a user model setup through devise. A user can have many clients. Each client then will have one to many projects/campaigns. My question is how can I pass the client id to the project/campaign in a form, or is there a 'rails way' to do it?

My project form is below. I was thinking something like a hidden field would do it but how do i find the client id.

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
         <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
         <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :client_id, :value => @client.id %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up your system like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients
end

#app/models/client.rb
Class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :projects
end

#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

Your schemas would be as follows:

```
users
id | email | etc | etc

clients
id | user_id | name | email | etc | etc

projects
id | client_id | name | etc | etc
```

---

**Form**

To save a new project based on a client (if you can only have one client per project), you'd use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :clients do
 resources :projects
end
```

This would create this route structure:

```
http://your-app.com/clients/15/projects/new
```

This will mean you will have the variable `params[:client_id]` available (through the route). I would then merge the param on the controller, using strong params:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
private
def params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :etc, :etc).merge(client_id: params[:client_id])
end
```

---

**Adding Clients To Project**

To add `clients` to a `project`, you'd have to deal with the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association, like this:

```
#app/models/project.rb
Class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :client_projects
    has_many :clients, through: :client_projects
end

#app/models/client_project.rb
Class ClientProject < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :project
end

#app/models/client.rb
Class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :client_projects
    has_many :projects, through: :client_projects
end
```

This uses a `join model` (`client_projects`), which will look like this:

```
client_projects
id | client_id | project_id | created_at | updated_at
```

This will create a separate table, which you'll be able to assign as many `clients` to any project you want. This would only be necessary if you wanted to have multiple clients per project, whereas the former idea would be if you had one project per client

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rich, been a great help

Answer (score 0):

If a `Client` `has_many :projects` then `Project` `:belongs_to :client`.

Then you can simply do

`@project.client_id`

See [Rails Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Edit:  Oh wait, I seem to have misunderstood.  At this point the project doesn't belong to the client yet?  You want to assign the client to the project?